# token_get_all y token_name devuelven error?

Tags: php, tokens

estoy probando las dos funciones `token_get_all` y `token_name` pero al ejecutar:

```php
<?php
$test = '
<?php ' . PHP_EOL . '
$array=["data1","data2"];
' . PHP_EOL . ' ?>
';

$tokenstring = token_get_all($test);
foreach ($tokenstring as $key => $arraytoken) {
    $tokenname = token_name($arraytoken[0]);

//esto es para la verificación por pantalla.
    echo '<pre>';
    echo var_dump($tokenname, $arraytoken);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

me devuelve el siguiente error:

> Warning: token_name() expects parameter 1 to be int, string given in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\t5\BOH-Basic-Output-Handler\src\OutputHandler.php
> on line 327 NULL string(1) "="
>
> Warning: token_name() expects parameter 1 to be int, string given in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\t5\BOH-Basic-Output-Handler\src\OutputHandler.php
> on line 327 NULL string(1) "["

***no se que tengo mal.***

Comment: El error marca que estás pasando un parámetro tipo *string* al método `token_name`, cuando se espera un parámetro de tipo entero (*int*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema está en que al analizar la cadena dada en `$test`, no todos sus elementos son [*tokens* T_SR](https://www.php.net/manual/es/tokens.php), por lo tanto el valor devuelto por [`token_get_all()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.token-get-all.php) no será otra cosa más que el mismo elemento.

Según la documentación:

> **Valores devueltos**
>
> Un array de tokens identificadores. Cada token identificador individual es al mismo tiempo un carácter único (por ejemplo: ;, ., >, !, etc...), un array de tres elementos conteniendo el índice de token en el elemento 0, el contenido del string del token original en el elemento 1 y el número de línea en el elemento 2.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Una solución es determinar si el elemento devuelto en `$arraytoken[0]` es de tipo entero, para ello podemos apoyarnos en el método [`gettype()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.gettype.php):

```php
if( gettype($arraytoken[0]) === 'integer' ) { ... }
```

Así podemos usar de forma segura el método [`token_name`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.token-name.php) sobre dicho valor.

Por ejemplo, tu código podría lucir así:

```php
<?php
$test = '<?php ' . PHP_EOL . '$array = ["data1","data2"];' . PHP_EOL . ' ?>';

$tokenstring = token_get_all($test);
foreach ($tokenstring as $key => $arraytoken) {
    if(gettype($arraytoken[0]) === 'integer') {
      echo "Esto es un token";
      $tokenname = token_name($arraytoken[0]);
      echo '<pre>';
      var_dump($tokenname, $arraytoken);
      echo '</pre>';
    } else {
      echo "Esto NO es un token";
      echo '<pre>';
      var_dump($arraytoken);
      echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

Otra forma es verificar si efectivamente `$arraytoken` es de tipo `Array`, apoyándonos en el método [`is_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.is-array.php) (particularmente esta me gusta más):

```php
<?php
$test = '<?php ' . PHP_EOL . '$array = ["data1","data2"];' . PHP_EOL . ' ?>';

$tokenstring = token_get_all($test);
foreach ($tokenstring as $key => $arraytoken) {
    if(is_array($arraytoken)) {
      echo "Esto es un token";
      $tokenname = token_name($arraytoken[0]);
      echo '<pre>';
      var_dump($tokenname, $arraytoken);
      echo '</pre>';
    } else {
      echo "Esto NO es un token";
      echo '<pre>';
      var_dump($arraytoken);
      echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.